# Is there a way to determine when CSS parsing/rendering has completed?

Tags: css, dom, rendering, benchmarking, reflow

I am wondering for benchmarking purposes if there is a DOM event or other way to determine when the browser has finished parsing/rendering the CSS. I'm trying to optimize CSS selectors and need a way to measure the drawing/rendering/reflowing times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome/Chromium there is a built in profiler which includes rendering. This is what it looks like when run on this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1PQi.png

Press Ctrl-Shift-J to access the developer tools in Chrome.

I'm sure that Firebug has something similar for Firefox.

Comment: Although, if this is in firebug, I've never seen it.

Comment: Paint info in Firebug: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug-paint-events/